# Invalid input detected at '^' marker while configuring network point-to-point

Tags: networking, router, cisco-router

I am beginner and I am using cisco router for my work. this is the steps I followed

```
>config terminal

#interface tunnel1

#description ""

#ip address <> <>
```

I want to do sth similar to `isis enable lax` command from arista router in cisco, I found this line

```
#ip router isis
```

till here, it works fine, but when I try `isis network point-to-point` it says

```
)#isis network point-to-point
                                   ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.
```

I also tried

```
)#ip router isis net point-to-point
                                                  ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.
```

but the error goes to point-to-point part

Can anyone could help me out ?
Thanks

Comment: the marker points to blank space beyond the intended input. perhaps there is a terminal issue. If using copy'n'paste, ensure you aren't capturing non-printable characters. Try pasting into notepad and then recopying that.

Answer (score 1):

IP-IP tunnels are inherently point-to-point interfaces (or at best PtMP). While I currently don't have IOS running that would include IS-IS support and cannot test this theory, I would assume that the command doesn't work on any PtP interface type because the mode you're trying to set would be the only possible mode anyway.